# How to extract a specific string with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to retrieve Bitcoin prices from CoinMarketCap.com.

I'm using Python along with requests and bs4.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"

header = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

data = requests.get(headers = header, url = link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')

bitcoinPrice = soup.find(id="quote_price")

print(bitcoinPrice)
```

So when I run the script, I have the following result with some additional code that I don't want. I just want the Bitcoin price.

```
<span data-currency-price="" data-usd="9806.68980398" id="quote_price">
<span class="h2 text-semi-bold details-panel-item--price__value" data-currency-value="">9806.69</span>
<span class="text-large" data-currency-code="">USD</span>
</span>
```

How do I extract the Bitcoin price from that chunk of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should give you what you want:

```py
bitcoinPrice.span.contents[0]
```

contains

```
'9808.16'
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. I can't seem to find any documentation for the 'span' and 'contents' method.

Comment: `bitcoinPrice` is a class of type Tag. `span` is a field that contains `<span>` HTML tag, which, again is Tag class. Tag class has `contents` field - check the docs [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree).

Answer (score 1):

```
bitcoinPrice = soup.find("span", class_="details-panel-item--price__value").text
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly give me the price, still a long string.

Comment: it gives you span tag to get value 9806.69 you have to do bitcoinPrice.text

Answer (score 0):

This is another way using css selector.

```
print(soup.select_one('.details-panel-item--price__value').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [official API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) under the basic (free) plan and then simply add your API key into below. Code example updated from [here](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest).

```
from requests import Request, Session
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'
parameters = {
  'id':'1'
}
headers = {
  'Accepts': 'application/json',
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'api_key',
}

session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

try:
    response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    #print(data)
    print(data['data']['1']['quote']['USD']['price'])
except (ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects) as e:
    print(e)
```